# day and month are reversed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell with the following content:

```
01/02/2015
```

The cell is date formatted.

Then I copy the value and put it in my module class:

```
Set Line = New CTravelLine
Line.Date= Cells(1, 8).value
```

Everything works fine until the moment I put this value in another cell:

The value 01/02/2015 becomes 02/01/2015.
I am using this format (dd/mm/yyyy). I have the impression that when the days are numerically lower than the month, the 2 values are reversed. The values are reversed whatever the method I tried:

Method 1:

```
Dim WrdArray() As String, datetest As String
WrdArray() = Split(travelLine.Date, "/")
datetest= WrdArray(0) & "/" & WrdArray(1) & "/" & WrdArray(2)
Cells(5, 5) = datetest
```

Method 2:

```
Cells(5, 5) = travelLine.Date
```

I don't understand how I can solve this problem.

Comment: What format is your windows regional settings set to ?

Comment: First of all, you seem to be having a locale that is different to U.S. (VBA's default).

As you've noted, if your date's day number is smaller than month, your formatting setting will flip them accordingly. However, you need to be aware that it is just the text that is displayed in the cell that gets formatted but not the actual value of cell.

Your problem, thus, is a conflict between the locale formatting and the actual cell value format. To circumvent that, your best bet would be to set the cell formatting to Text rather than date.

Comment: If your cell contains a true date value, and the Date property of your travelLine class is an actual Date type, this shouldn't happen. If either of the aforementioned is text, you will have this issue and should use CDate when working with the text.

Comment: in your vba where you open the workbook, you'll need to indicate local=true like this: Set wkbkname = Workbooks.Open(fileNames(index), local:=True)

Answer (score 3):

This might have happened due to 'Regional formatting problem'.

Excel has a habit of forcing the American date format (mm/dd/yyyy) when the dates have been imported from another data source. So, if the day in your date happens to be 1 - 12, then Excel will switch the date to mm/dd/yyyy.

When dates are imported from a text file, there is an option in the VBA code to apply regional format which corrects this problem.

**OR**

Change number format of date column in excelsheet from 'date' format category to 'text'; save it. 
(After Saving run the VBA Code if you have any. Now check whether the date format is 'text' or changed back to 'date'.)

If it has changed back to 'date' try to fix it as 'text'

If it's 'text'; Correct the erroneous date cells and save the excel sheet. This will make dates not to change automatically to American Format.

Comment: What is the option to force VBA to recognize a special formatting ? I'm having troubles with `CDate` when comparing to a Word Date Field which recognize the format without issue but `CDate` invert days and month.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you .

Let me explain what I want to do :

1. I have a csv file with some date.
2. I copy a range of my sheet in variable table. The range contain some columns with dates.
3. I make some manipulations on my table (very basic ones)
4. I transpose my variable table (since only the last dimension of a variable table can be increase)

5. I put my variable table on a new sheet.

What I found:
There is no date issue after executing step 1-4. The date issue shows up when writing on the sheet...

Considering what Avidan said on the post of Feb 24 '15 at 13:36, I guess it is excel which forces the American format mm/dd/yyyy... So I just change the date format at the very beginning of my program :

Before starting any manipulation date:

1. do
   .Cells("where my date is") = Format(.Cells("where my date is"), "mm dd yy")
2. execute your program
3. write the table on a sheet
4. back up to the date format you like directly on the sheet

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, I had a similar problem where the dates are working just fine in some cells but keep flipping in others regardless if I copy paste or enter manually, I did the whole data text to column and cell formatting solutions and all of that didn't work.

The solution actually is not in excel, it's in the region and language setting.

To have the dates display as MM/DD/YYYY in the formats tab change the format to US.

To have the dates display as DD/MM/YYYY in the formats tab change the format to UK.

Answer (score -2):

Just use:

```
Line.Date = cDate(Cells(1, 8).value2)
```